# Move bitmap ship on canvas with finger without jump

Tags: java, android, canvas, action, move

I try to move a bitmap on canvas with ACTION_MOVE and event.getX/Y()
It works fine, but when i put finger on screen the ship jump in my finger position.
How can i move it withoit this jump?
for exemple: my ship is in position X=5. I put finger in position X=7 and after drag it from X=7 to X=10. The ship jump from X=5 to X=7 and after follow my finger from X=7 to X=10;
But i want that: when i put finger in X=7 the ship stay in X=5 and when i drag finger from X=7 to X=10 the ship translate from x=5 to X=8 where 8=10-7+5.

Comment: The `MotionEvent` offers a `getHistoricalX()` and `getHistoricalY()` method. This way you can calculate the difference between the current finger position and the last finger position. Then add this difference to the positions of the `Bitmap`, which you will most likely have to store globally in your class.

Comment: thanks but can you make an example.